# Are there any spaces with vanishing homotopy groups but not contractible?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm studying basic Algebraic Topology. Here is my question:

Let $X$ be a space with $\pi_i(X)=0$ for all $i$.

Then, $X$ should be contractible?

(If $X$ is CW-complex, then cell-by cell argument works and this is true.)

Comment: See the "quasi-circle" example in Hatcher, exercise 7 section 1.3.  It has trivial homotopy groups but it's not contractible. 

Comment: http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Double_comb_space

Comment: This type of question is probably best put on math.stackexchange.com, as its a common example in introductory algebraic topology courses. 